# Mid 2000s manga involving young people with super powers. As a child, the main character accidently caused his parents' death in a car accident

Tags: story-identification, manga, powers

First time posting on this forum but I’m looking for the name of a manga I read a bit of as a kid at my local library. It might have only been the first book. Mid 2000s, pretty dark subject matter.

Key points I remember:

- The MC is an orphan?
- When the MC was a child he accidentally kills his parents in a car accident when a soda can (grape or orange) rolls under the car brakes (I don’t know why but I remember this part super clearly, everything else from here on out is pretty fuzzy).
- It was loosely super power-based. There’s some event where lots of characters acquire powers, maybe mental powers, telekinesis etc..
- There’s a character, maybe an antagonist, who creates holes through things, walls, people, etc., by waving his hands at them, maybe pointing at them. I don’t remember what was punching the holes in or it being explained. This character might have gone on a violent rampage?
- The characters were roughly high school-aged? Maybe middle school but not old?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Also posted to Reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/1359fu4/what_manga_is_this/), where *[Saishuu Shinkateki Shounen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alive:_The_Final_Evolution)*, aka *Alive: The Final Evolution* was suggested, and accepted by the querent.

[image: Front cover of Alive: The Final Evolution]

> The series follows Taisuke Kanou, a teenage student in Japan who lives a normal life with his sister Yoko Kanou and his friend Hirose. The story begins when an alien being flies towards Earth after sensing life emanating from there. It is learned that the being, Akuro, is composed of souls who were granted immortality but preferred to die but could not do so without a body. These beings separate from each other and enter the bodies of humans in order to pursue death. As a result, a large number of people begin to commit suicide worldwide and the incident became known as Nightmare Week. The humans who resist Akuro's influence gain powers from their possession and become known as "Comrades."

....

> **Taisuke Kano**
> Taisuke Kano (叶 太輔, Kanō Taisuke) is the main character of the series. He is haunted by guilt for his role in the accident that killed his parents. After his parents died, he was raised by his older sister, Yoko Kanō (叶 陽子, Kanō Yōko). Taisuke's ability is destruction and reconstruction. Though unable to fully use his reconstruction abilities, Taisuke is able to manifest his destruction abilities by emitting fire which permanently damages cells.

....

> **Yuichi Hirose**
> Yuichi Hirose (広瀬 雄一, Hirose Yūichi) was Taisuke's best friend. He is a timid and shy boy who is often bullied, but saved by Taisuke. After Nightmare Week, Hirose becomes a comrade allowing him to fire spheres which can annihilate anything. After he accidentally murders his bullies, Hirose is put into police custody where Katsumata brainwashes him into joining him to search for a piece of Akuro's Heart. He complies after kidnapping his childhood friend, Megumi. Upon absorbing the piece of Akuro's Heart, his body becomes intangible and he gains the desire to destroy all life on Earth.